# Platforms Spawning Every Frame Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

So I'm working on a 2D platformer game and in part of it platforms are being sent at a contant rate but what the game does is it makes one every frame. I'm using an IEnumerator to make the delay.

```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;

public class ButterPlatformCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject butter;
public Vector2 setpos;
public Talking trial;
public Talking script;
public Vector2 platpos;
public Rigidbody2D platform;
public float speedleft = -75;
public float spawnInterval = 1f;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnPlatforms());
}

IEnumerator SpawnPlatforms()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (script.trialtwo == true)
        {
            Rigidbody2D platformInstance = Instantiate(platform, platpos, platform.transform.rotation);
            platformInstance.velocity = new Vector2(speedleft, 0);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnInterval);
    }
}

void OnColliderEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Delete"))
    {
        Destroy(collider.gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: suggesting spawnInterval has been made 0, or you changed time.. so .. yes.. possibly

Comment: I don't see where it was made zero

Comment: maybe  in the Inspector? if you e.g. added the `= 1f;` afterwards it will already have been serialized with the value `0`

Comment: You haven't really mentioned what object you have attached this script to. The name and the `OnColliderEnter` make me suspicious that this script is running on the same platform that you're spawning in.

Comment: @Voidsay in that case it wouldn't spawn an object each frame but either exponential or result in a stack overflow and crash right away though ;)

Comment: @derHugo sure, but for the first second it would be one every frame, next second two every fame and so on. If you don't test long enough you wouldn't even notice.